# Probelm with shift+alt+down or shift+alt+up

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04

I am trying to customize a shortcut in Visual Studio Code for copy lines up. I want that <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> make a copy of line above current line but I could not assign this shortcut in VS Code.

After some research I look into my keyboard shortcuts in GNOME. I tried to remap my <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> key for open terminal to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> but it did not work there either.  I tried both left and right <kbd>alt</kbd> keys.

I think it is not VS Code issue because it is working fine on Windows.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 and please let me know if you need anything else related to above issue.

Answer (score 2):

I Just fix my problem there are various questions asked here that helped me to give me idea what was happening

After reaching i found that my <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> was not working because they were changing my input method and i just disable it from `gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: So where exactly do I have to go in Tweaks_

Comment: I completly disabled `Tweaks` but this doesn't work. It was same as previous.